# Highcharts: To bold last total value of stacked column

Tags: highcharts

I been trying to bold the last total value of this stacked column. Help needed.

Thanks in advance!

It keep asking me to write more
It keep asking me to write more
It keep asking me to write more
It keep asking me to write more
It keep asking me to write more
It keep asking me to write more

http://jsfiddle.net/leslie20/ekyLqz47/

```
$(function () {

         Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
              VMLRadialGradientURL: 'http://code.highcharts.com/{version}/gfx/vml-radial-gradient.png',  // Path to the pattern image required by VML browsers in order to draw radial gradients.
              canvasToolsURL: 'http://code.highcharts.com/{version}/modules/canvas-tools.js'            // The URL to the additional file to lazy load for Android 2.x devices. These devices don't support SVG, so we download a helper file that contains canvg, its dependecy rbcolor, and our own CanVG Renderer class.
            },
            title: {
                align: 'left',
                style : { color: '#f7921e',fontSize: '14px', fontWeight: 'bold'}
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    groupPadding: 0.1,
                    pointWidth: 28,
                    padding: 2
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                tickColor: 'null',
                lineColor: '#4d4d4f',
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.isLast) {
                            return '<span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 12px">' + this.value + '</span>';
                        }
                         else {
                           return this.value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                itemStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'normal'
                }
            },
            credits: {enabled: false},
            lang: {
              loading: 'Loading...', // The loading text that appears when the chart is set into the loading state 
              thousandsSep: ','  // The default thousands separator used in the Highcharts.numberFormat method unless otherwise specified in the function arguments.
            }
            // tooltip: {enabled: false}
          });

$('#container6').highcharts({
            chart: { type: 'column' },
            title: { text: 'Cash Distribution Per Share (Declared)'},

            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    '2010',
                    '2011',
                    '2012',
                    '2013',
                    '2014'
                ]
            },
            legend: {
                reversed: true,
            },

            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                gridLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
                title: {text: ''},
                labels: { enabled: false },
                stackLabels: { 
                    enabled: true,
                    y: -3,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return  Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total, 1);
                    },

                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {

                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',

                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.y:,.1f}',
                        style: {
                          textShadow: false, 
                      }
                    }

                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Special dividend<br>(cents)',
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: 'Special dividend: <b>{point.y:,.1f} cents</b>'
                },
                color: '#414042',
                data: [3.5, null, 1.7, 7.1, null],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        if (this.y != 0) {
                          return this.y;
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }, {
                name: 'Final dividend<br>(cents)',
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: 'Final dividend: <b>{point.y:,.1f} cents</b>'
                },
                color: '#f7921e',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'normal'

                    },
                },
                data: [7.7, 7.9, 6.3, 7.1, {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bolder',
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        },
                    },
                    y: 11.9
                }],



            }, {
                name: 'Interim dividend<br>(cents)',
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: 'Interim dividend: <b>{point.y:,.1f} cents</b>'
                },
                color: '#939598',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    },
                },
                data: [6.3, 6.6, 6.6, 6.8, {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bolder',
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        },
                    },
                    y: 7.0
                }],

            }]
        });


    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I only want the last value (18.9) to be bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [stacklabels formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.stackLabels.formatter) and then check last tick on xAxis compared with current x of stacklabel. If this is the same, then bold that.

```
formatter: function () {
                var ticks = this.axis.chart.xAxis[0].tickPositions,
                    len = ticks.length,
                    last = ticks[len - 1];

                if(this.x === last) 
                    return '<span style="font-weight:bold">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total, 1) + '</span>';
                else
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total, 1);
            },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ekyLqz47/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just set the [`yAxis.stackLabels.style.fontWeight`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.stackLabels.style) to 'bold' instead of 'normal'.

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    gridLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        y: -3,
        formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total, 1);
        },
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I only want the last value (18.9) to be bold.